# (Ubuntu - Lamp) phpmyadmin install error 404 not found

Tags: ubuntu, lamp

I install apache, mysql, php and then phpmyadmin on ubuntu desktop 10.04 version
I test apache: localhost with browser and its works.
I test mysql with console and its works.
*I test phpmyadmin http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ and get **error 404 not found***
I see that solution for that brobem, copy /phpmyadmin/ to /www/, but I dont want to put in /www/
to my websites files (maybe I wrong or miss something-please tell me in this case).
How this problem can be solved in the best way?
Thanks

Comment: I got a phpmyadmin 404 error aftern I upgraded to PHP 5.5, which automatically (I guess?) updated to Apache 2.4 also. Apache 2.4 changes its `conf.d` folder to `conf-enabled`. Full path: `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/`. So you have to copy your phpmyadmin link over there. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19176094/631764

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you use the package manager to install phpMyAdmin or did you install it from source? If you did install it using the package manager a configuration should already be in place but could be disabled. Take a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin for an Ubuntu specific explanation. This is how you can configure Apache to make phpMyAdmin available if you installed it from source:

Use the `Alias` directive in the Apache configuration to make phpMyAdmin available without placing it withing the `DocumentRoot`. This is how it should look like:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /path/to/phpmyadmin
```

Please take a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_alias.html#alias. Also note the explanation about granting access using a `<Directory>` section when you get a "Forbidden" error and make sure the file system permissions are correct.

Comment: Another option is to create an Apache vhost for the mysql subdomain and set it's DocumentRoot to /usr/share/phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

These may seem obvious but:

- Try /phpmyadmin/ rather than /phpmyadmin
- Make sure you have restarted apache after installing phpmyadmin

Good luck!